# Apply $digest on specific directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a clock using angular-js. Now I have built a clock using `$interval`, but After every interval other `$directive` are also getting refresh which I want to restrict.

**Html File**

```
<body ng-app="defaultDashboard">
    <div ng-controller="timeDisplay">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell nav-link navbar-textColor" id="clock"> {{time}} </span>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="panel">
        {{ printName('hello man!!') }}
    </div>
</body>
```

**Angular File**

```
angular.module('defaultDashboard',[])
    .controller('timeDisplay'function($scope,$filter,$timeout,$interval){

    $scope.time = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');     
    var timeRefresh = function(){
        $scope.time = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }
    $interval(timeRefresh,1000);
})

.controller('panel',function($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.printName = function(string){
        console.log(string);
    }
});
```

the clock is working fine but in the console, after every second it is printing:

```
hello man!!
hello man!!
hello man!!
hello man!!.....
```

Comment: clock should be a directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal behavior when we use **$interval**.

Angular normally re-render everything on $rootScope.$digest(), which is called by $scope.$apply(), $interval etc.

But, there is one backdoor for this problem to repeat rendering of some part of the code. **In your case clock**.

Separate your views into different scopes.

Eg:- The clock that updates every 1000 ms (1 sec) could be in its own controller, separating it from the scope with the heavy directive. **In your case printName() function**.

Then use any ***non-Angular other JS interval*** (e.g. **setInterval()**) **instead of $interval** to update your clock, and call $scope.$digest() manually.

***Eg:-*** Change your JS file to:

```
angular.module('defaultDashboard',[])
    .controller('timeDisplay'function($scope,$filter,$timeout,$interval){

    $scope.time = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');     
    var timeRefresh = function(){
        $scope.time = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }

    // don't use $interval, it'll call $rootScope.$apply()
    // $interval(timeRefresh,1000);
    // Instead use setInterval with 1000ms value.
    setInterval(function () {
        timeRefresh();

        // digest only our scope, without re-rendering everything else.
        $scope.$digest();
    }, 1000);
})

.controller('panel',function($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.printName = function(string){
        console.log(string);
    }
});
```

Comment: clock should be a directive. No need of setInterval, this is not an angular way

Comment: This is what my approach would be.
Kindly, let us know any better way to achieve this.

Comment: @kuldeep gupta Then kindly, accept this answer by clicking right and up arrow button in front of answer...No need to call Sir...I'm also a Student when it comes to programming...It's my pleasure...Thank you...